# Does U:={A ∈ Mn×n(R) | rank(A) ≤ 1} define a subspace of Mn×n(R) of real (n × n)-matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't really know where to start with the exercise. Obviously the subspace axioms have to be checked but how would that work when we're only given information about the rank? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense as it shows that it is not closed under addition thank you!